# Question about big o

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have trouble starting this homework assignment for my discrete math class.
Does $\Theta(n^3+2n+1) = \Theta(n^3)$ hold?  Justify your answer.

We need to prove $n^3+2n+1 \in \Theta(n^3)$ AND $n^3 \in \Theta(n^3+2n+1)$\

First lets solve $n^3+2n+1 \in \Theta(n^3)$

This is where I'm getting stuck. I'm supposed to do something with transitivity but I don't entirely know how to do that. Do I use the definitions like:

$l|n^3| \leq n^3+2n+1 \leq k|n^3|$
let $l = 1$ and $k=1$

and so on?

Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Let $k=4$ and $3n^3\geq 2n+1$ for all $n\geq n_0$ for some $n_0$ (which you can find, probably $n_0=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)
$$
f\in O(g)\text{ as }x\rightarrow a
$$
whenever
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\infty
$$
in this case since

$$\dfrac{n^3+2n+1}{n^3}\to1$$

we have that $n^3+2n+1∈O(n^3)$ and $n^3∈O(n^3+2n+1)$.

Comment: oh, I didn't see I could use a limit to help prove that.

Comment: @JorgeSepúlveda in this way it is straightforward

Comment: Was the method involving transitivity more complicated? How is that method?